# In oracle DBA Database connections beyond 500 connection

Tags: oracle

One of the production DB connections exceeds 500. How to resolve this issue.
Could you please provide ASAP.

Comment: probably, you can limit the connection and disconnect the idle session manually.

Answer (score 1):

1. Find out from where all are you initializing the connections.
2. Find out why are these connections not being closed
3. Resolve issues if any
4. Find out if you require higher capacity servers.